# How to set UINavigationController Image for only one view and then another image for the rest of the views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to set the background image for my navigation controller. On the very first view i want to display a different image and then same in every other view. 
Currently what i got is i am able to display the image on first view but somehow i am not able to remove it and its overlapping with other image on the next view.
Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    navImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    navImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_dashboardFirst.png"];
    WBWAppDelegate * appDelegate = [(WBWAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appDelegate.rootNav.navigationItem.titleView = navImage;


}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    navImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_dashboard_header.png"];
    WBWAppDelegate * appDelegate = [(WBWAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appDelegate.rootNav.navigationItem.titleView = navImage;

}
```

Comment: Throw a breakpoint into the viewWillDisappear and check if its even being called, if you haven't already. You could also try putting it into viewDidUnload. I haven't played around enough with those so I'm just throwing out ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way to do this is to do the same thing you did here in the viewDidLoad: in the viewDidLoad: of the next controller. The viewWillDisappear: has caused me some trouble before aswell, I'm not really sure why.

**EDIT**

You could check if any of the following methods work:

```
– viewWillDisappear:
– viewDidDisappear:
– viewDidUnload
```

These are the only methods I could think of that might work.

Comment: Tha i know but here i have like 15 views and i don't want to change this for each and every view. So i am looking for some solution which can be implemented here and will reflect every where else.

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope it helps else i can't assist you, sorry.